# How to create special ROOT_OPS in Template-Toolkit?

Tags: perl, internationalization, locale, template-toolkit, dancer

I use [Locale::TextDomain](http://search.cpan.org/~guido/libintl-perl-1.23/lib/Locale/TextDomain.pm) in a [Dancer](http://search.cpan.org/~yanick/Dancer-1.3111/lib/Dancer.pm) environment with [Template-Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/index.html).

And yes, I know [Dancer-Plugin-I18N](http://search.cpan.org/~koceasy/Dancer-Plugin-I18N-0.41/lib/Dancer/Plugin/I18N.pm) and tried it, but I don't wan't to use it!

I read [Defining_Custom_Virtual_Methods](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html#section_Defining_Custom_Virtual_Methods) and adjusted it do my needs.

```
# load Template::Stash to make method tables visible
use Template::Stash;

$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{ 'localize' }    = sub {
    return __(shift); 
};
```

and in a view

```
[% localize("Hello")  %]
```

That works very well.

But I would like to wrapp all the [Locale::TextDomain functions](http://search.cpan.org/~guido/libintl-perl-1.23/lib/Locale/TextDomain.pm#EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS) like:

```
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__}    = sub { return __x(shift) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__x}   = sub { return __x(shift, @_) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__n}   = sub { return __n(shift, shift, shift) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__nx}  = sub { return __nx(shift, shift, shift, @_) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__xn}  = sub { return __xn(shift, shift, shift, @_) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__p}   = sub { return __p(shift, shift) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__px}  = sub { return __px(shift, shift, @_) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__np}  = sub { return __np(shift, shift, shift, shift) };
$Template::Stash::ROOT_OPS->{__npx} = sub { return __npx(shift, shift, shift, shift, @_) };
```

but unfortunately it is not possible the use '__' or '__x'
as token.

So my question: How do I create '__' (and friends) root operations in Template-Toolkit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template Toolkit doesnt export functions that start with _ because they are considered private. You can get around this by setting the following before your Stash operations:

```
$Template::Stash::PRIVATE = 0;
```

Comment: Great. Now I read about it in http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html. Must have missed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The lexer does not recognize them as identifiers. Changing the module to accept leading `_` appears to be far from trivial.

Comment: That was your question, and that's what I answered.